# D3, javascript function scope with setInterval and clearInterval and event handler

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js, setinterval, clearinterval

I am using one button to start, stop, and resume an Animation in D3.

Inside 'animateTheMap' function, I assign  setInterval to 'animateTimer' to begin the animation, and attach a click event to the same button to stop the animation with a callback function 'stopAnimateTheMap'.

However, the stopAnimateTheMap function cannot see 'animateTimer'; hence throws "animateTimer' is not defined.

1) Do I need to merge two functions or is there a way to resolve this?
2) I add more than one 'click' events to the same button to play and stop the animation. Is this an optimal / appropriate way to handle the event? I had initially created each variable for each event and assigned them to the button.

Thank you,

```
var animateMapButton = d3.select('body').append('button').attr({   
                                        class: "button",
                                        id: "animateMap"})
                              .text("Animate the map")

animateMapButton.on("click", animateTheMap)

function animateTheMap(){
                                    animateMapButton.text("Stop the Animation")
                                    animateMapButton.on('click',stopAnimateTheMap)
                                    i=0;                      

                                    var animateTimer = setInterval(function(){

                                        if(i<yearArray.length){
                                             i++;
                                             d3.select('text.selected').classed('selected',false)
                                             d3.select('#year'+yearArray[i]).classed('selected',true)
                                             updateMapColor(yearArray[i])

                                          }
                                        else{
                                          clearInterval(animateTimer)
                                        }
                                      },2500)
                          }


 function stopAnimateTheMap(){

                                  clearInterval(animateTimer)    
                                  animateMapButton.text("Animate the map")                                        
                                  animateMapButton.on("click",animateTheMap)
                              }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1): You just need to declare the animateTimer variable outside the function.

For 2): I would just use one click handler that toggles between animating and not animating.

```
var animateMapButton = d3.select('body').append('button').attr({   
        class: "button",
        id: "animateMap"})
    .text("Animate the map")

animateMapButton.on("click", toggleAnimating)

var animateTimer;
var isAnimating = false

function toggleAnimating(){
    if (isAnimating) {
        clearInterval(animateTimer)    
        animateMapButton.text("Animate the map")                                        
    }
    else {
        animateMapButton.text("Stop the Animation")
        i=0;                      

        animateTimer = setInterval(function(){

            if(i<yearArray.length){
                i++;
                d3.select('text.selected').classed('selected',false)
                d3.select('#year'+yearArray[i]).classed('selected',true)
                updateMapColor(yearArray[i])

            }
            else{
                clearInterval(animateTimer)
            }
        },2500)
    }

    isAnimating = !isAnimating;
}
```